# ElasticSearch nodes information that aren't running

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

What is the reliable way to distinguish between a single-node Elasticsearch cluster and a two-node cluster in which one of the clusters is **temporarily unavailable**

What I have tried

1) NodesInfoRequest will not reliably return information about nodes that aren't running.

2) Looking at the number of unassigned shards - this only tells            you that there aren't enough nodes to satisfy the number of              replicas specified.

Any pointers will be great

Comment: The only way I can imagin is to check logs for leaving nodes. Dont know an api for that.

Comment: Why do you need this information?